# Does anyone know why res.download is giving my download file a random name each time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, download

I'm using express 4.17.1. When I try to use res.download to send a csv file to the browser, the file is downloaded but the file name is something like this: 3d6a8bc1-696c-40f2-bae8-29ca69658534.csv

Then, when I attempt to download the same file again, it will send the file under this name: c1cd40ff-ea9d-4327-9389-9768fb53384a.csv

Each time it is a different random string of characters.

My code is simply this:

```
res.download(filePath, 'list.csv');
```

The filePath is this: ./downloadables/mail-list-14da.csv

I've tried using sendFile but got the same result. I recently updated from a previous version of express to see if it would automagically resolve this issue but it is still doing this.

**EDIT: More Code Below as Requested**

Here is the entirety of the request endpoint:

```
/*
 * Download the list specified by the list_id with the appropriate fields as specified by the
 * list_type parameter.
 */
router.get('/download/:list_type/:list_id', authCheck('list'), function(
  req,
  res,
  next
) {
  let listData = {};

  Voter.aggregate(aggrPipelineList(req.params.list_type, req.params.list_id))
    .allowDiskUse(true)
    .exec()
    .then(voterDocs => {
      if (voterDocs && voterDocs.length === 0) {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: `list_id ${req.params.list_id} not found`
        });
      } else {
        listData.voter_docs = voterDocs;
        return req.params.list_type;
      }
    })
    .then(listType => {
      if (listType === 'mail') {
        return generateMailExportFile(req.params.list_id, listData);
      } else if (listType == 'phone') {
        return generateCallExportFile(req.params.list_id, listData);
      } else {
        return generateFacebookExportFile(req.params.list_id, listData);
      }
    })
    .then(filePath => {
      console.log('FP: ' + filePath);
      res.download(filePath, 'list.csv');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ message: err.message }); // @note: added message
    });
});
```

Also including the generateMailExportFile function for completeness. Yes, I know I can refactor the three generate export file functions. It's on my list... I originally wrote this before I knew what the hell I was doing.

```
generateMailExportFile = function(listID, listData) {
  let fields = [
    'First Name',
    'Last Name',
    'Suffix',
    'Street Address 1',
    'Street Address 2',
    'City',
    'State',
    'Zip'
  ];
  let fileName = 'mail-list-' + listID.substr(listID.length - 4) + '.csv';
  let voterRows = buildVoterRowsForMailList(listData.voter_docs);
  let csv = json2csv({ data: voterRows, fields: fields });
  let tempServerFilePath = './downloadables/' + fileName;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(tempServerFilePath, csv, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(tempServerFilePath);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Here is the redux/thunk function that requests the file download:

```
export const downloadList = (listId, type) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const rshttp = new RSHttp(getState);
    rshttp
      .get('/list/download/' + type + '/' + listId)
      .then(response => {
        let file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'text/csv' }),
          url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(url);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error Downloading File: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  };
};
```

I hadn't before thought about the problem being on the react side. If I find an answer, I'll update this question. Any thoughts are still greatly appreciated!

Comment: The line looks fine to me, and should work according to the docs, maybe the error is somewhere else?

Comment: maybe a client-side issue? What's the code in the browser?

Comment: Can you show us more of the code for that request handler? It's difficult to understand what might be going on otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are recreating the file on your front-end. You can simply change your `React` code to:

```
export const downloadList = (listId, type) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    window.open('http://localhost:8080/list/download/' + type + '/' + listId', '_blank')
    // Replace with your backend URL :)
  };
};
```

and it will download the file with the correct `filename`.